# Unix check if a file referenced by any symlinks

Tags: unix

How to check if a **file is being referenced by any symlinks** in the directory - I want to delete all the other files except the symlink and the refernced file. Is there any direct command to check or a work around to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If the symbolic link is in the same directory or in a well known one, that would be easy. Just check if no other file share the same inode `ls -d1Li`.

Otherwise, there is no direct way to know if a symbolic link exist to any given file. Even exploring all mounted file systems wouldn't be reliable, as the link might exist on a currently unmounted  filesystem, or on a remote machine accessing the file remotely (NFS, CIFS and the likes).

Comment: its in the same directory, and the file which is referred for e.g 
present -> 7.0
when the refered file is updated its
present ->7.1(symlink to new file,removes link to the old one)
in the same folder,
i want to delete the old file which is no longer linked & and this happens frequently so need the clear up the space without deleting the required file...any suggestions on this?...

Comment: @user1534373  Suggestion: stop using symbolic links.  use hard links instead, and delete files for which the link count is < 2